# Delete SQL data from database with php page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making an application to secure doors and windows in your house. The app is done for 80% but i can't figure out how I can delete a database record of a door of house. The problem is I can't find a way to read out the right data to delete the record. Could you please look in my scripts i made for the delete page?

I have one page to insert al the data in a table to overview all the devices that are "connected" to the app.

```
<section>
        <form action="verwijderen.php" method="post">
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT device_id, naam, plaats.plaats, type.type, status FROM devices, type, plaats, status 
                        WHERE devices.type_id = type.type_id 
                        AND plaats.plaats_id = devices.plaats_id
                        AND status.status_id = devices.status_id";

                    $result = $con->query($sql);
                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
                    {
                        echo '<table><tr><td>ID</td><td>Naam</td><td>Plaats</td><td>Type</td><td>Status</td><td>Verwijderen</td></tr>';

                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                        {

                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>' .$row['device_id']. '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' .$row['naam']. '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' .$row['plaats']. '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' .$row['type']. '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' .$row['status']. '</td>';
                            echo '<td>';
            ?>

            <input type="submit" value="Verwijderen" name="submit">
        </form>                             
                <?php '</td>';
                        }
                    echo '</table>';                        
                    }
                ?>
</section>
```

The other page I have is the page to delete the records that are inserted into the table. The problem with the deleting is I can't find a way to delete the records. Adding the records to the database in html with a $_POST/$_GET works fine..

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
include '../dbconnect.php';

//$connection = mysql_connect("", "", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server
//$db = mysql_select_db("cerar", $connection); // Selecting Database from Server
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    { // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL

    }       
    mysqli_close($con); // Closing Connection with Server
    //header( "refresh:3;url=index.php" );
?>
```

Comment: Your form tag is closing multiple times. Move it out of the loop. Or move the opening tag inside the loop.

Comment: In what way will that help me deleting my records form the database?

Comment: I explained that in my answer. I just wanted to highlight that you currently have an invalid HTML structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a form for each row of your table, and include a hidden input field containing the key value to pass to the server. So move the opening `form` tag just before the `input type="submit"` you have, and include another hidden input, like this:

```
    <form action="verwijderen.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?=$row['device_id']?>" name="device_id">
        <input type="submit" value="Verwijderen" name="submit">
    </form>
```

Then in PHP you can find the device id that must be deleted in `$_POST['device_id']`. It should be easy to write the delete statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section>
    <form action="verwijderen.php" method="post">
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT device_id, naam, plaats.plaats, type.type, status FROM devices, type, plaats, status WHERE devices.type_id = type.type_id AND plaats.plaats_id = devices.plaats_id AND status.status_id = devices.status_id";
        $result = $con->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            echo '<table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Naam</th>
                            <th>Plaats</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Verwijderen</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>';
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>' .$row['device_id']. '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' .$row['naam']. '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' .$row['plaats']. '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' .$row['type']. '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' .$row['status']. '</td>';
                        echo '<td>';?>
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['device_id']; ?>" name="device_id">
                            <input type="submit" value="Verwijderen" name="submit">
                        <?php '</td>';
            }
            echo '</tbody>
            </table>';
        }
    ?>
    </form>
</section>
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
include '../dbconnect.php';
extract($_POST);
//$connection = mysql_connect("", "", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server
//$db = mysql_select_db("cerar", $connection); // Selecting Database from Server
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Verwijderen')
    {
        //delete query
        //DELETE FROM devices WHERE device_id = $device_id
    }       
    mysqli_close($con); // Closing Connection with Server
    //header( "refresh:3;url=index.php" );
?>
```